# How can I get previous Site URL using PHP

Tags: php

I have some problem. 
So I would like to use

```
 $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

and then basically disply it.

So this is what I'am doing right now.

```
 $previousUrl = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
echo $previousUrl;
```

I would like to display url using echo. But it doesn't work.

Can somebody explain to me what An I doing wrong?

King regards,

Artur.

Comment: is it set? it wont always be, its a browser set variable

Comment: The browser supplies the referrer information. It is not required to be sent and very likely that browsers/users just don't send it. Unless the previous page is on your site, you likely won't even be able to tell what the previous page is.

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` is set by the browser. You won't generally see it unless you've followed a link from somewhere and there is actually a referring site. It may be absent, or spoofed, or just wrong. Don't rely on it.

Comment: So is there any other option to get previous url correctly? I would like to check if previous url was Facebook, twitter.

Comment: http is a stateless protocol - so no

Comment: It is a setting in the Browser.  It is a bone of contention between the Browsers and those that like to track Referer. e.g FireFox v. Google.  FireFox a couple years back threatened to ship with REFERER default set to to off.  It used to be a setting easily accessible setting in the  Tools=>Options dialog.  Now it buried in the About:Config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately you have to rely on the user and their browser configuration.

If they clicked on a link from another site and the user doesn't have anything (plugins, etc.) blocking the referrer, `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will be populated.

If they visited the site directly or they are blocking `HTTP_REFERER` the value will be blank and there's no way for you to access it.

Comment: Thank you, well I fixed it, with facebook and with twitter it work correctly

Comment: it has NOTING to do with particular sites.

Comment: Not sure what you mean @Dagon. I mean if the user wasn't blocking the referrer if that clarifies my statement.

Comment: It is a Browser configuration setting.  It is the Browser that originates and transmits Referrer. There is no other entity involved and therefore no entity to block it other than the receiving Server or the transmitting Browser.

Comment: sorry @mkaatman my comment was aimed at To dO who said it was 'fixed' for those 2 sites.

Answer (score 1):

### From RFC7231:
 Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Semantics and Content

The "Referer" [sic] header field allows the user agent to specify a
   URI reference for the resource from which the target URI was obtained
   (i.e., the "referrer", though the field name is misspelled).  A user
   agent MUST NOT include the fragment and userinfo components of the
   URI reference [RFC3986], if any, when generating the Referer field
   value.

```
 Referer = absolute-URI / partial-URI<br><br>
```

The Referer header field allows servers to generate back-links to
   other resources for simple analytics, logging, optimized caching,
   etc.  It also allows obsolete or mistyped links to be found for
   maintenance.  Some servers use the Referer header field as a means of
   denying links from other sites (so-called "deep linking") or
   restricting cross-site request forgery (CSRF), but not all requests
   contain it.

Example:

```
 `Referer: http://www.example.org/hypertext/Overview.html`
```

If the target URI was obtained from a source that does not have its
   own URI (e.g., input from the user keyboard, or an entry within the
   user's bookmarks/favorites), the user agent MUST either exclude the
   Referer field or send it with a value of "about:blank".

The Referer field has the potential to reveal information about the
   request context or browsing history of the user, which is a privacy
   concern if the referring resource's identifier reveals personal
   information (such as an account name) or a resource that is supposed
   to be confidential (such as behind a firewall or internal to a
   secured service).  Most general-purpose user agents do not send the
   Referer header field when the referring resource is a local "file" or
   "data" URI.  A user agent MUST NOT send a Referer header field in an
   unsecured HTTP request if the referring page was received with a
   secure protocol.  See Section 9.4 for additional security
   considerations.

```
  Some intermediaries have been known to indiscriminately remove
```

Referer header fields from outgoing requests.  This has the
   unfortunate side effect of interfering with protection against CSRF
   attacks, which can be far more harmful to their users.
   Intermediaries and user agent extensions that wish to limit
   information disclosure in Referer ought to restrict their changes to
   specific edits, such as replacing internal domain names with
   pseudonyms or truncating the query and/or path components.  An
   intermediary SHOULD NOT modify or delete the Referer header field
   when the field value shares the same scheme and host as the request
   target.

Answer (score -2):

It should work out as you wrote it, or like

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

If there is no referer or the previous site used a dereferer, the result might be wrong or does not exist.

Comment: What's the point?  How does it differ functionally from `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.  And it will not work out when it is often not there.  The code will have to assume it will not be available no matter the purpose.

Comment: The point is, that you won't receive a notice or warning for using a variable which is null ;)

Comment: You need to reconfigure your `error_reporting` if you are getting those messages.